# why continuous assignment is not permitted in input reg type variable?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Just continuous assignment in reg type that is declared inside module is perfectly working.(<CODE 1>)

However, continuous assignment in reg type that is declared in input give rise to error that says "has more than one continuous driver".(<CODE 2>)

```
module test_1;
  reg as;
  assign as = 0;
endmodule
```

<CODE1>

> perfectly works

```
module test_2(
input reg as
);
    assign as = 0;
endmodule
```

<CODE2>

> This code instigates error "ERROR VCP2979 "Variable ""as"" has more than one continuous driver."

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed only one continuous assignment to a variable *or* any number of procedural assignments. An `input` port variable counts as an implicit continuous assignment, so you cannot add another assignment.

Net can have multiple continuous assignments. See my article https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/05/03/wire-vs-reg/

Comment: I read the article you introduced me through site. I understood as "Since two continuous assignment to same variable are executed concurrently, that variable doesn't know which continuous assignment to apply for final result". Is this right way to interpret the verilog assignment system?

Comment: Correct. Wires on the other hand have strengths associated with them to help resolve which assignment _wins_.